# Fold region of org file

Tags: org-mode, region

Is there a way to fold a region in org-mode? (Not the whole file, and not an individual item, but a region containing multiple items.)

Often I want to collapse only a portion of an `org` file, say folding:

```
* a
** a1
** a2
* b
** b1
** b2
** b3
* c
** c1
** c2
* d
** d1
** d2
```

into

```
* a
** a1
** a2
* b ...
* c ...
* d
** d1
** d2
```

I know in this particular example I could simply fold the whole file using `org-cycle`, then expand `a` and `d` individually, but imagine there are hundreds of items and I want to fold a dozen contiguous items contained in an active region while leaving the rest of the items in the file expanded.

Comment: How would this be different than using the `C-tab` functionality? Using `shift-tab` cycles the entire file, but `C-tab` folds a particular tree.

Comment: Have you tried recording a [keyboard macro](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html)?

Comment: @Melioratus I would rather use a built-in feature or elisp since I do this very often.

Comment: @GJStein I have updated the question which hopefully clarifies what I am seeking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to do what you want :

```el
(defun org-hide-subtrees-in-region (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (save-restriction
    (narrow-to-region beg end)
    (outline-hide-sublevels 1)))
```

EDIT: I first gave a wrong solution, which I keep here as it is also interesting IMO (but doesn't answer the question)

The function `outline-hide-region-body` seems to be exactly what you want, but for some reason it is not interactive. We could add an interactive spec to it, but let's just define `org-hide-subtrees-in-region` as :

```el
(defun org-hide-subtrees-in-region (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (outline-hide-region-body beg end))
```

Comment: Excellent, this works! Would it be possible to make this behave like `org-cycle` on the region?

Comment: @holocronweaver I don't have an obvious solution in mind.